# AngularJS E2E : Find element by tag name

Tags: jquery, angularjs, element, protractor, angularjs-e2e

According to this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element, the method "find()" allows to find an HTML element by tag name.

I tried this in my code :

```
element.find('button').click();
```

And my HTML code is :

```
<button ng-click="getMessage()">Request service as {{name}}</button>
```

But the button is never clicked.
I don't want to use classes, ids, or weird selectors. I think I'm just missing something but I'm unable to find exchaustive docuementation (about "finders").

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What is `element` in your context? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing AngularJS's `angular.element` class with Protractor's global function `element` of the same name.

Protractor creates a few global functions such as `browser`, `element`, `by` and `protractor`.

`element` is a function and not an object. As such, they have no property methods like `find(..)`. The `element` function takes a selector object as an argument. To create a selector object you have to use the global `by` object. This object contains a number of handy selector functions such as `id`, `model`, `binding`, etc.. etc..

If you want to use jQuery/CSS selector syntax. You can use the `by.css()` function.

Example;

```
 element(by.css('button')).click();
```

This will find the first `button` tag and click it. Use `element.all(...)` to find all of them.

You can also narrow this to only buttons that bind the scope variable `name`

```
 element(by.css('button')).element(by.binding('name')).click()
```

More on locators:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

Comment: Thanks for the reference. And yes, I confused angular.element with protractor.element

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will by helpful in your case:

```
element(by.partialButtonText('Request service as'));
```

Comment: This can fit my needs. Thank you